# sublime alt+ (some letter)

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2

This is my first question on stackoverflow so be gentle!
Anyway I'm using sublime as my main text editor and I am remapping my arrow keys from the arrows to <kbd>ALT+I</kbd>, <kbd>ALT+J</kbd>, <kbd>ALT+K</kbd>, and <kbd>ALT+L</kbd>.

I have noticed that on ubuntu 14.04 after I remap my keys that when I click <kbd>ALT+I</kbd> the menu at the top of sublime is now in focus and has a drop down opened up! The other 3 keys seem to work for moving the cursor.
I have tried to figure out how to disable the menu bar at the top of the screen from getting selected anytime <kbd>ALT+I</kbd> is pressed but I can't figure it out. I'm pretty sure it is an operating system problem as opposed to a sublime issue.

Can anyone shed a little light on the subject?
I have already tried to disable the "activate the window menu" in keyboard shortcuts. It didn't seem to work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Welcome to SO, a community for *programming* questions. Though you maybe using Sublime Text for writing code, this is not a programming question; you should search for a similar question or post on [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: Ok sorry about that! Thanks for the heads up! I guess I assumed this was for programming related questions as well. Thanks!

Comment: Questions about tools *are* on-topic on SO, but this seems to be an edge case, more related to your OS than the tool itself.